# Running a script in .bashrc

Tags: linux

I have a script that I have to run in order to use a particular application.  I figured that instead of manually running the script from the terminal everytime, I thought I could add the script to .bashrc so it will run automatically.  But when I do that I get a "permission denied" error when I source .bashrc.

How should I properly add a script to be run from .bashrc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script is most likely not executable. Try `chmod +x your_script`.